# Queryset in __init__ Form Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-queryset

```
class PaymentSelectForm(forms.Form):   
    date_from = forms.DateField()
    date_to = forms.DateField()
    website = ModelChoiceField() 
    paymentmethod = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PAYCODE_CHOICES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentSelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        applyClassConfig2FormControl(self) 
        self.fields['website'].queryset=Website.objects.all()
```

I have errors: TypeError: `__init__()` missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'. How can I use `Queryset` in `__init__` Form?

Comment: I don't get why you want to do that in the `__init__`, and not in the construction of the field itself?

Comment: IS this django-admin form? or simple one?

Comment: use forms.ModelForm instead of forms.Form.

Comment: @AnupYadav: but the error arises from the `ModelChoiceField` construction, so regardless what type of `Form` we use, it will *always* error, since we never construct the `PaymentSelectForm` class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless there is some information you are currently hiding, you better **declare the queryset in the declaration of the `ModelChoiceField`**:

```
class PaymentSelectForm(forms.Form):

    date_from = forms.DateField()
    date_to = forms.DateField()
    website = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Website.objects.all()) 
    paymentmethod = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PAYCODE_CHOICES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentSelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        applyClassConfig2FormControl(self)
```

In case the queryset is *dynamic* (this is not the case here), you can **set it to `None` initially**, and then overwrite it in the `__init__` function:

```
class PaymentSelectForm(forms.Form):

    date_from = forms.DateField()
    date_to = forms.DateField()
    website = ModelChoiceField(queryset=None) 
    paymentmethod = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PAYCODE_CHOICES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentSelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        applyClassConfig2FormControl(self)
        self.fields['website'].queryset=Website.objects.all()
```

But this is usually the case if for instance the `queryset` depends on parameters that are passed to the form, or it depends on other tables (and it can not be written into an SQL query elegantly).

Answer (score 2):

Use `widget.choices`

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentSelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        applyClassConfig2FormControl(self) 
        self.fields['website'].widget.choices=(
            (choice.pk, choice) for choice in Website.objects.all()
        )
```